# How do you do the "therefore" (∴) symbol on a Mac or in Textmate?

Tags: textmate, symbols

Is there a way to write the ∴ therefore symbol with keyboard shortcuts in Textmate or just on a mac?

Comment: SuperUser.com is for these questions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do this often, you can create a keybindings file in your Library to map it to a key combination.

In ~/Library create a directory named KeyBindings. Create a file named DefaultKeyBinding.dict inside the directory. You can add key bindings in this format:

```
{
    "x" = (insertText:, "\U23CF");
    "y" = (insertText:, "hi"); /* warning: this will change 'y' to 'hi'! */
}
```

The LHS is the key combination you'll hit to enter the character. You can use the following characters to indicate command keys:

```
@ - Command

~ - Option

^ - Control
```

You'll need to look up the unicode for your character (in this case, ∴ is \U2234). So to type this character whenever you typed Control-M, you'd use

```
"^m" = (insertText:, "\U2234");
```

You can find more information here: http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html

Comment: Tips: (1) Use a new instance of TextEdit to test your bindings config is working each time you make a change (2) Applications will need a restart for your bindings to take effect!

Answer (score 8):

First you use a full stop, then you hold down alt and press the letter H and put in another full stop.
.˙.

Comment: worthy innovation, newgaf

Comment: there is no 'alt' on a Mac (not to be snarky: I tried this with Option for 'alt' and it doesn't work)

Answer (score 5):

From System Preferences, turn on the "Show Keyboard & Character Viewer in menu bar" setting.

Then, the "Character Viewer" menu will pop up a tool that will let you search for any unicode character (by name) and insert it ∴ you're all set.

Comment: This is also available in Edit > Special Characters…

Comment: In Character Viewer, if you add the symbol to favourites, you can access it easily by typing Ctrl+Cmd+Space (which also provides a link to the full character viewer)

Comment: The emoji picker (⌘^Space) also has special characters. You can search for "therefore" or hit the double arrow in the bottom right (≫) to browse symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The emoji picker (⌘^Space) has special characters. You can search for "therefore" or hit the double arrow in the bottom right (≫) to browse symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If using WORD for mac
enable 'use maths autocorrect rules outside maths regions'
Type \therefore

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to insert the therefore symbol into a WORD DOCUMENT

Hold down the ALT key and type 8756

Hope the answer ur question
Regards Al~Hash.

Comment: That applies to a Windows computer, not a Mac

Comment: I ended up here while I was looking for Windows solution. Thanks